# Upgraded Firebase - Getting error on FirebaseApp.configure()

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, xcode7.3

I upgraded Firebase today and now I am having a very unusual problem

> Use of unresolved identifier FirebaseApp.

I have done everything as per the documentation provided by firebase *[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#initialize_firebase_in_your_app)*. I have insert `GoogleService-Info.plist` on my project and pod i have install are as follows:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core
pod 'Firebase/Database
pod 'Firebase/Messaging
```

I am using XCode 7.3.1 and my deployment target is 9.0

Any insight you can give is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Have u added "import Firebase"?

Comment: yes i have done that

Comment: btw have u builded your solution? It will also build pods

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. They have renamed it to FIRApp.

Use `FIRApp.configure()` instead

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a potential bug in the latest release.

Try specifying `import FirebaseCore` instead.

Comment: I dont using it in my swift file, where i'm using FirebaseApp.configure()

Answer (score 1):

On the terminal, run

```
pod update
```

solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Try deleting and uploading you Google file this way:

Instead of dragging the Google file directly into your Xcode project, right click the folder (inside your Xcode project) that you would like to save the Google file and click "Add Files to '[App Name]'..." and add GoogleService-info.plist that way. Also make sure the file is called "GoogleService-info.plist".

Answer (score 0):

1. Install relative Firebase packages

   ```
   pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
   ```
2. Import Firebase in Xcode

   ```
   #import <Firebase.h>
   ```
3. Add firebase configure. I attached screenshot

   ```
   if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
       [FIRApp configure];
   }
   ```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Your solution appears to be for Objective-C, but the question is explicitly about using Swift.

Comment: @Eddan Zhang Can you explain how this solves the issue?

Comment: Also, the screenshot is not necessary, if you include a code snippet in the post.